# Reactjs call function from another component

Tags: reactjs, api, components

I want keep api function in separate page but I couldn't call Login api call function from login component

**Console error - TypeError: _services__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.UseApi.Login is not a function**

```
//services
export const UseApi = () => {
    const Login = (email, password) => {
        axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password})
           .then((result) => {
           });
    }
}


// login component
import { UseApi } from "./services" ;
const Login = () => {
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        UseApi.Login(email, password) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useApi` is a function with another function `Login` defined inside it.

either return the function from `useApi` function

```
export const UseApi = () => {
    return (email, password) => {
        axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password})
           .then((result) => {
                // code
           });
    }
}
```

and call it as `UseApi()(email, password)`

or just remove the nested function

```
export const UseApi = (email, password) => {
     axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password})
     .then((result) => {
          // code
      });

}
```

and call it as `UseApi(email, password)`

Another approach could be to return an object from `UseApi` function that contains the `login` function

```
export const UseApi = () => {
    return {
        login: (email, password) => {
          axios.post('/api/login', { email: email, password: password})
            .then((result) => {
                // code
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and call it as `UseApi().login(email, password)`